# Make the design on a webpage static

Tags: html, css

Starting out with a basic e commerce website, I have a nice header design with a logo and some navigation. What I noticed was that when I zoom in and out on the page holding **ctrl + scrolling** the content on the website moves around, this also applies when I resize the web window using the resize button on the top right corner of the browser and dragging around the borders of the browser.

The design and content of my site gets really misplaced and distorted when I do this. Divs and text overlapping, etc...

Is there anyway I can make the content not move around at all, so that it is static? What I want more specifically is that when you resize the browser the web content just gets hidden where the browser windows has been resized.

Here is my HTML / CSS:

```css
#cartlist {
     float: right;
     margin-right: 353px;
     margin-top: -50px;
     padding-left: 300px;
     
    }

    #carttext {
     font-family: arial;
     margin-left: 50px;
     margin-top: -51px;
    }

    #text {
     font-size: 14px;
    }

    #count {
     font-size: 12px;
     margin-top: -28px; 
    }

    #img a:hover {
     background-color: e3e3e3;
    }

    #img a {
     padding-top: 25px;
     padding-right: 150px;
     padding-left: 5px;
     padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

    #headerbackground {
     background-image: url(bit.jpg);
     background-repeat: repeat-x;
     margin-top: -10px;
     margin-left: -10px;
     margin-right: -10px;
     padding-bottom: 1px;
     
    }

    #headernav {
     margin-left: 244px;
     padding-top: 5px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     margin-right: 250px;
    }

    #headernav li {
     display: inline;
     font-family: arial;
     font-size: 11px;
     padding-left: 0px;
     padding-right: 32px;
    }

    #headernav li a {
        text-decoration: none;
      color:black;
    }

    #headernav li a:hover {
     color:adadad;
    }

    #headerlogo {
        margin-left: 280px;
        margin-right: 680px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }


    #nav {
     margin-left: 240px;
     margin-right: 675px;
     margin-top: 24px;
    }

    #nav li {
     display:inline;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-family: arial black;
     padding-left: 0px;
     padding-right: 0px;
    }


    #nav li a{
     text-decoration: none;
     color:white;
     background-color: 0f0f0f;
     padding:8px 19px;

    }

    #nav li a:hover{ 
     background-color: 333232;
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <head lang = "sv-se">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SSDKUNGEN</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge;chrome=1" >
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="header.css">
    </head>

    <body id = "body">

    <div id ="header">
    <div id ="headerbackground">
    <ul id ="headernav">
    <li><a href ="">HEM</a></li>
    <li><a href ="">LOGGA IN / REGISTRERA DIG</a></li>
    <li><a href ="">INFOCENTER</a></li>
    <li><a href ="">OM OSS</a></li>
    </ul> 

    <div id ="headerlogo">
    <img src="ssdkungen.png" style="width 410px;height:41px;">
    </div>


    <div id = "cartlist">
    <p id = "img"><a href = ""><img id = "cart" src ="cart.png";></a></p>
     <div id = "carttext">
     <p id = "text">Din kundvagn</p><br>
     <p id = "count">kundvagnen är tom</p>
     </div>
    </div>

    <ul id ="nav">
    <li><a href ="product_list.php">PRODUKTER</a></li>
    <li><a href ="installation_guide.php">INSTALLATIONSGUIDE</a></li>
    <li><a href ="ssd_info.php">OM SSD</a></li>
    </ul> 

    </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

The code is a mess but I just want some advice on my issue.

Comment: So when you zoom in and out, e'thing should stay as they are... however, when you change the browser size, all the elements that does not have fixed size, will start moving. You have to ensure that you set the height and width of every single element.

Comment: While your question is valid, it's really too broad. Everyone is going to start answering with opinions. There are about 100 ways to do this. Check out http://alistapart.com. Hiding divs and content with CSS are things that will get you penalized in terms of SEO.

Comment: What if you change this meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>` to `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">` ... just change the width value to watever you need

Comment: @Chris the problem with setting a minimum width like that is that you end up completely destroying usability for your users on a variety of devices. If someone is using a tablet, cell phone, or even an older < 1024px resolution display computer, the site will not render correctly.

Comment: @Jdsfighter i agree... but OP says "What i want more specificaly is so when you resize the browser the web content just gets hidden where the browser windows has been resized." Not sure if I misunderstand? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible method is to set a minimum width for the page. However, this can and will prevent the page from being responsive.

```
html, body {
    min-width: 1000px;
}
```

You can also use a templating system, like Bootstrap, which will allow you to design the pages in a way that are centered around a grid system. This allows you to gracefully collapse your layout for smaller screens and resolutions.

Comment: @Jdsfighter Thank you! I checked out bootstrap but it says it is for mobile devices but it works for pc aswell? Anyway, i think ill stick with the simple answer you gave me in the meantime. Say, is it possible to design a whole other page for mobile devices, using the same database as the desktop version? So that you wont need to fiddle around with stuff like bootstrap?

Comment: Bootstrap is a templating "engine" of sorts. It's for all devices, all screens, etc. You can craft your site around their grid system and it enables you to designs your site to gracefully display across a variety of different devices and screens.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested your code yet but it sounds like a problem with responsiveness. As mentioned you can do this easily with a framework like Twitter Bootstrap or by setting the size of your container divs using percentages instead of px. You should use media queries to set specific styles for certain screen sizes, for example:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
   ...write your styles here
}
```

If you want to hide content use
    display: hidden;
inside of a media query to hide that element when the window reaches a certain screen size. 
Also you should wrap all of your body content in a div. This div should use pixels for its width/height because the rest of your elements' percentages will be based off of that divs relative size.